# Center 3 images in one line without additional container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three images in the row. I want to make them centered in one line, but I can't use additonal container like, `div`, etc. When I add this style:

```
img {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

images are centered but each in separate line. I need to make them being in one line. Is there any way to do that using standard CSS? I tried `display: inline-block`, but that doesn't work.

Currently I can't paste my markup, however all my images have set `max-width: 100%; height: auto;`. Total width for images is full `container-fluid` width (I use Twitter Bootstrap)

Comment: paste yor html as well, it depends whats the width of image and total width available?

Comment: can you show us your script?

Comment: show your markup, please

Comment: @Ty221 we don't have enough details yet. we need to see what css settings are being set on the images. the div's that their inside, and what is the size of your images.

Comment: if you can't copy and paste the markup at least provide a basic example on jsfiddle

Comment: @MorHaviv That may be difficult to post code, because this is markdown/Jekyll website only with elements of CSS

Answer (score -2):

you can center them without css

```
<center><img src="x1.jpg"><img src="x2.jpg"><img src="x3.jpg"></center>
```

Comment: If I am not false `center` is deprecated

Comment: @Ty221, you're right, `center` is completely obsolete.

Comment: Why are you advising someone to use an element that was deprecated in HTML4 and removed in HTML5?

Comment: Just because some browsers still support it doesn't mean you should use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center